# haskell pattern match numbers (deconstruction)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Can pattern matching in Haskell be used for deconstructing numbers in this way:

```
f (n + 1) = n
```

I expect predicessor for ex: f 6 = 5,  f 5 = 4 etc.

I found such kind of pattern matching usage here:
https://wiki.haskell.org/Continuation

```
 facCPS :: a -> (a -> r) -> r
 facCPS 0 k = k 1
 facCPS n'@(n + 1) k = facCPS n $ \ret -> k (n' * ret)
 facCPS 4 (+ 2) :: Integral a => a
```

but in my ghci it does not work:

Prelude> f (n + 1) = n
:4:12: error: Parse error in pattern: n + 1

Maybe some options need to be added? can I use somehow use pattern matching in this way?

Comment: This *used to* be possible, but was then removed. You might be able to turn it back on with a language pragma; I'm not sure. You're looking for "n+k patterns".

Comment: {-# LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns #-} will make that example work.

Comment: It's worth noting that `f n = n - 1` will have exactly the same effect, and requires no language extensions. (You might have to rewrite the base case of the recursion though.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond of course, there are often several ways to do things, but the question was about deconstruction and pattern matching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the example from the wiki that you quoted:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns #-}
fac :: Integral a => a -> a
fac 0 = 1
fac n'@(n + 1) = n' * fac n
```

This was removed from the language in 2010, but Haskell remains a very configurable language. :)

Comment: thx, I also add it in ghci with Prelude> :set -XNPlusKPatterns
Prelude> f(n + 1) = n
Prelude> f 5